# BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-12105-10] disconnect: not connected (req=1)

Tags: android, opencv, tensorflow-lite

Application getting crashed when USB device disconnect after connection done. I got below logcat error message. I am not much aware about this.

> Logcat error:

```
E/tflite: Can not open OpenCL library on this device - dlopen failed: library "libOpenCL.so" not found
E/tflite: Falling back to OpenGL
E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-8293-2] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x57 in tid 8884 (Thread-11), pid 8293
```

If USB device not disconnect then application working fine but sometimes it's disconnecting after USB device attach and connection done.